# Skip the first line of CSV file

Tags: python, csv, sqlite

I'm having an issue with my python csv parser and I don't know where the mistake happens :

So this is my python :

```
# -*-coding:Utf-8 -*                                                                                                                                                                                        

import sqlite3;
from datetime import datetime, date;

conn = sqlite3.connect('info_max.sqlite3')
conn.text_factory = str
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('drop table if exists info_max')
c.execute('create table info_max(id_huiles text, name_fr text, name_ln text, img text, mode_obt text, bien_vertus text, bio text)')

def mysplit(string):
    quote = False
    retval = []
    current = ""
    for char in string:
        if char == '"':
            quote = not quote
        elif char == ',' and not quote:
            retval.append(current)
            current = ""
        else:
            current += char
    retval.append(current)
    return retval

# Lit de ligne en ligne, en sautant la première ligne                                                                                                                                                       
rawdata = open("info_max_try.csv", "r").read()
data = rawdata.split("\n", 1)[1:]
data = re.split('"END"', rawdata)
print(data)
for entry in data:
    # Parse les valeurs                                                                                                                                                                                     
    vals = mysplit(entry.strip())
    # Convertit les strings format heure au format standard sqlite3                                                                                                                                         
    # Insert la ligne                                                                                                                                                                                       
    vals[0] = int(vals[0])
    print "Inserting %s..." %(vals[0])
    print "The enrty is : %s" %entry
    sql = "insert into info_max values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
    c.execute(sql, vals)

# Done !                                                                                                                                                                                                    
conn.commit()
```

My `.csv` looks like this :

```
"id_huiles","name_fr",    "name_ln",  "img",         "mode_obt",  "bien_vertus","bio"
"77",        "Basilic", "Basilium", "Basilic.png", "some_text", "some_text",    "0"
...
```

And I got this error after 3 entries :

```
File "parseAromaHuile.py", line 39, in <module>
    c.execute(sql, vals)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 7, and there are 6 supplied.
```

**EDIT**

My lines had `\n`in them .. I modifed my code but I don't want my parser to read my first line

The offending line looks like this:

```
"6","Bergamote", "Citrus bergamis L.", "bergamote.png", "some_text", "some_text\n other_text\n more_text","0"
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I don't know why someone voted to close it, I have IMHO well documented my question, the disired behaviour is i don't want this error .. I want my 7 columns to be filled

Comment: You should consider using the csv-module in python, instead of hand-parsing things yourself. Beyond that, without seeing the data of the actual failing line, there is little what we can do - the natural assumption is obviously that for whatever reason that line contains only 6 entries, or your parser makes that happen.

Comment: My parser works fine for everything, I just created a new CSV and this happens

Comment: add a `print len(vals)` before executing the sql-insert.

Comment: Yeah my line has only 6 columns. I don't detect a mistake, is it possible, if the text is too long that python/sqlite reject it ?

Comment: i would rather guess the error is in the elif statement. Try reseting the quote there: `quote=False`, the default size-limit for text is over 1Gb afaik.

Comment: I used the same csv, removing the text and it works fine. So maybe My text has too many \n or something like that ..

Comment: sizelimit of varchar/text: http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q9

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62347/discussion-between-don-question-and-nicolas-charvoz-kurzawa).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62391/discussion-between-nicolas-charvoz-kurzawa-and-don-question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in your `mysplit` function, somewhere (this if/elif seems suspect) it returns a list of 6 elements instead of 7.

Try this:

```
import sqlite3;
import csv
from datetime import datetime, date;

conn = sqlite3.connect('info_max.sqlite3')
conn.text_factory = str
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('drop table if exists info_max')
c.execute('create table info_max(id_huiles text, name_fr text, name_ln text, img text, mode_obt text, bien_vertus text, bio text)')


with open('info_max.csv','rb') as source:
    #I use csv reader instead of writing my own
    data = csv.reader(source, delimiter=';')
    header = data.next()
    for vals in data:
        for val in vals:
            #I use replace function to get rid of qoutes
            val.replace('"', '')
        #adds the string "missing data" if some column is missing in your source 
        if len(vals) < 6:
            vals += ['missing data' for i in range(0,6-len(vals))]                                                                                                                                                                                       
        vals[0] = int(vals[0])
        print "Inserting %s..." %(vals[0])
        print "The enrty is : %s" %vals
        sql = "insert into info_max values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
        c.execute(sql, vals)

conn.commit()
```

Comment: File "parsing.py", line 16
    for vals.replace('"', '') in data[1:]:
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

Comment: Sorry to bother your I'm new to python but I got a new error : File "parseTry.py", line 14, in <module>
    data = csv.reader(source, delimiter=';')
NameError: name 'source' is not defined

Comment: '_csv.reader' object has no attribute '__getitem__'Haha again an error, is it me or just "not testing again" ? :p

Comment: heheh sorry but I think this is you.. `csv.reader(source, delimiter=';')` it's working on my machine.. sounds like csv module is corrupted.. see this link for reference on csv module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62400/discussion-between-nicolas-charvoz-kurzawa-and-hrabal).

Answer (score 0):

Your peculiar problem may lay in the readline function, which would split a longer text containing newlines into two entries/lines/data-sets instead of one! ;-)

The canonical way to parse csv would be to use the csvreader-module as pointed out by Hrabal.